# Custom android dialog looked weird

Tags: android, listview, dialog, android-edittext, android-dialog

I trying to make a dialog, which has `listView` and also two `editText`.

**Dialog code**

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_add_task:
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
                alertDialog.setView(convertView);
                ListView lv = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                EditText username = (EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.username);
                EditText pass = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.password);
                ArrayList<ToDoList> search = new ArrayList<ToDoList>();
                DialogAdapter adapter=new DialogAdapter(getApplication(),search,lv,username,pass);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                alertDialog.show();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

**DialogAdapter**

```
public class DialogAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    private static ArrayList<ToDoList> search;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    ListView listview;
    EditText User,Pass;

    public DialogAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ToDoList> searchList,ListView listview,EditText user,EditText pass) {
        search=searchList;
        this.listview=listview;
        this.User= user;
        this.Pass=pass;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return search.size();
    }

    public ToDoList getItem(int position) {
        return search.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_with_edittext, null);
            holder= new ViewHolder();
            holder.name = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.username);
            holder.pass = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.password);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        holder.name.setText(search.get(position).getDate());
        holder.pass.setText(search.get(position).getTask());
        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        EditText pass;
        EditText name;

    }
}
```

**ToDoList**

```
public class ToDoList {

    private String task = "";
    private String date = "";

    public ToDoList(String task)
    {
        this.task= task;
    }

    public void setTask(String task) {
        this.task = task;
    }

    public String getTask() {
        return task;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return task;
    }
}
```

**custom_dialog**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</ListView>
```

**dialog_with_edittext**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:hint="Add new task" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:hint="Summary"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Snap Shot**

[image]

The dialog looked weird. What's wrong here ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all,the main reason nothing is showing up is because your `ArrayList<ToDoList>` has no items.

In your adapter's constructor you don't need to pass the `editTexts`, the `convertView` in your adapter will make sure to give you the references.

So here's your adapter class revisioned :

```
public class DialogAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private static ArrayList<ToDoList> search;
    ListView listview;
    Context mContext;


    public DialogAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ToDoList> searchList, ListView listview) {
        search=searchList;
        this.listview=listview;
        this.mContext = context;

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return search.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ToDoList getItem(int position) {
        return search.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder= new ViewHolder();
        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_with_edittext, parent,false);

            holder.name = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.username);
            holder.pass = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.password);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.name.setText(search.get(position).getDate());
        holder.pass.setText(search.get(position).getTask());
        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        EditText pass;
        EditText name;

    }
}
```

And for your dialog , try using the class [Dialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html) , so you can customize it easier :

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_add_task:

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    dialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog);

                } else {
                    dialog = new Dialog(this);
                }
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);

                ListView lv = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.listView1);


                ArrayList<ToDoList> search = new ArrayList<>();
                search.add(0,new ToDoList("example")); //populate your list here

                DialogAdapter adapter=new DialogAdapter(this,search,lv);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);

                WindowManager.LayoutParams params = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
                params.width = 800;
                params.height = 800; //create the window size however you like
                dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(params);
                dialog.setTitle("My dialog");
                dialog.show();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```